# JSP strange error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I am a newbie in JSP and this is my first JSP.

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hi There!</h2>
<br/>
<h3>Date=<%= new Date() %>
</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

On the line where I am creating Date object, Eclipse is giving error as

```
 Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
```

My Eclipse version is:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229

Comment: if I view the JSP on browser, it works fine. So i think its something with Eclipse warning.

Answer (score 1):

problem got solved when I added jsp-api.jar into build path of the project.